# executionStats: DocumentDB with NodeJS and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aws-documentdb

I'm unable to get `executionStats` from DocumentDB using mongoose and NodeJS.

```
await model.find({ order_id: payload.order_id })
        .sort({ updated_at: -1 })
        .limit(1)
        .explain('executionStats')
```

The same command works from `mongosh` and returns the execution time taken.
But when we try using mongoose, I'm getting this error:

```
MongoServerError: Field 'verbosity: allPlansExecution' is currently not supported
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/my-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:753:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at MessageStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
```

I need a built-in Database process to calculate the time taken to execute a query from NodeJS. But the above process isn't working.

Any idea on how to achieve this or to handle the above error?